# Label Offset function in R Mapview do not alter the position of the text

Tags: r-mapview

I have been trying to adjust the position of labels in Mapview. However, the functions that I have seen discussed won't work for me. The one that comes closest so far is addStaticLabels.

```
library(mapview) 
 mapview(breweries) %>% addStaticLabels(label = breweries$zipcode,
                              direction = 'left',
                              offset = c(12,-15),
                              textsize = "10px")
```

No matter what offset I give it doesn't change where the text is. This makes it really hard to see the text and the point.